# making a swf file into a linkable button

Tags: actionscript-2

I'm not very handy with actionscript 2 let alone 3, but I simply want to make the flash animation on my website entry page into a link that connects my about page. I understand  it can't be done the easy way with an href on the html page.  So my research tells me that I can somehow use an invisible button in the fla file, but I can never each the details.

I have made buttons in flash, but never something that uses the entire stage.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by the way click tag works, see how clicktag is implemented, thats excactly what you need.

oh, here's a link http://www.flashclicktag.com/

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer I will go to your link and give it a try!

Comment: I have Flash version 10.0.2, so it appears there's no point in trying this solution.  Any suggestions would be welcomed.